# Isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to third homotopy group of compact simple Lie group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be a compact connected simple Lie group. It is known that its third homotopy group $\pi_3(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. More precisely, there is a Lie group homomorphism
$$\rho:SU(2)\longrightarrow G$$
which induces an isomorphism
$$\rho_*:\pi_3(SU(2))\overset{\cong}{\longrightarrow}\pi_3(G).$$
(Recall that $SU(2)\cong S^3$ so $\pi_3(SU(2))=\Bbb Z$.)

Clearly, all conjugates of $\rho$ have the same property. Is there a Lie group homomorphism $\varphi:SU(2)\to G$ such that $\varphi_*=\rho_*$ but $\varphi$ is not conjugate to $\rho$?

Comment: E.g. $G$ may have outer automorphisms. But you probably would like to exclude these too?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm not sure how we would get $\varphi_*=\rho_*$. The point about inner automorphisms is that they can all be continuously deformed to the identity since $G$ is connected. I don't know any outer automorphism with this property.

Comment: I believe that Jacobson-Morozov applies to compact groups, i.e. maps $\phi$ up to conjugacy are indexed by conjugacy classes of nilpotents in the complex group. And then I think that the $\rho$s that you're interested in are the ones corresponding to short simple roots, so in particular, conjugate.

Comment: @user104853 Well, any automorphism of $G$ acts by post-composition on $\pi_3(G) = \mathbb{Z}$, and therefore must take $\rho$ to either itself or $-\rho$ in $\pi_3$.

Comment: If I'm correct, the outer automorphism of $\mathfrak{su}_n$ acts as the identity on $\pi_3$ (I use identification with $H_3$ and then identification of the latter to the (predual of) 1-dimensional space of invariant quadratic forms, working now in $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ as we can complexify). It is true that automorphisms of compact simple Lie groups always act as the identity on $\pi_3$?

Comment: @YCor: yes, if $G$ is a simple simply connected Lie group, then $\pi_3(G)=H_3(G,\mathbb Z)$ is *canonically* isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. Similarly, $H^3(G,\mathbb Z)$ is *canonically* isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. For Lie algebra cohomology, $H^3(\mathfrak g,\mathbb R)=H^3(G,\mathbb R)$ is *canonically* $\mathbb R$. At the level of Lie algebra cohomology, one can write down a formula that makes it obvious that the isomorphism is canonical: the canonical generator of $H^3(\mathfrak g,\mathbb R)$ sends $X,Y,Z$ to $\langle [X,Y],Z\rangle$ where $\langle\,,\,\rangle$ is the basic inner product.

Comment: @AndréHenriques thanks, that's clear indeed!

Answer (score 11):

No, you cannot have $\varphi_*=\rho_*$ unless $\varphi$ is conjugate to $\rho$.

In fact, as observed by Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer ([1978, p. 455](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=506229)), $\varphi_*$ regarded as a map $\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z$ is just multiplication by the so-called *Dynkin index* of $\varphi_{\mathbf C}:\text{SL}(2,\mathbf C)\to G_{\mathbf C}$, i.e. "the ratio of the invariant inner products on both Lie algebras, each normalized to make the length of the highest root 2".

And as observed by Dynkin himself ([1952, Thm 2.4](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=47629)), all $\varphi$ of index 1 are conjugate (corresponding, as Allen Knutson says, to the minimal nilpotent orbit in $\mathfrak g_\mathbf{C}$): see the translation in ([2000, p. 197](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1757976)), or for another proof, Distler-Garibaldi ([2010, Lemma 4.5](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2669443)).

Comment: Conjugate means conjugate by an element of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$? or of $G$ (inner automorphism)?

Comment: @YCor Of $G$. (Note OP asks for $\varphi_*=\rho_*$, not $\pm\rho_*$.)

Comment: What happens then to an outer automorphism of order 3 on $\operatorname{SO}(8)$?

Comment: So I guess the conclusion about automorphisms is... if $f \in \text{Aut}(G)$ acts trivially on $\pi_3$, then the image of $\rho$ can be conjugated to land inside $G^f$?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე it acts trivially on $\pi_3$, and takes simple roots to other simple roots, that were already $W$-conjugate. In particular their root subgroups are conjugate. What's worrying you?

Comment: @AllenKnutson somehow I found it evident that if the whole bunch of simple roots cannot be conjugated to another one (as happens with an outer automorphism) then at least one must go to a non-conjugate of itself. I now see it was a wrong assumption but still do not see clearly enough what happens. Roots are all conjugate to their images, but when you try to find a single conjugating element for all of them you hit some obstruction. Can this obstruction be described in a "scientific" way?

Comment: Well on the afterthought the fact that the automorphism is outer says it all I think...

Comment: It's reminiscent of the concept of "fusion" of conjugacy classes, where two elements of $H<G$ may be $G$-conjugate without being $H$- or even $N(H)$-conjugate.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე it's clear that the action of automorphism on $\pm\rho_*$ factors through a subgroup of index at most 2, so automorphism of order 3 act trivially. But still I don't know if any automorphism maps $\rho_*$ to $\rho_*$, as I said in my comment to the question (if I'm correct, not in $\mathfrak{su}_n$).

Comment: @YCor Somehow it should be true that reflections of the Dynkin diagram which cannot be realized as a planar $180^\circ$ turn should reverse orientation, hence induce $-1$ on $H_3$ ($=\pi_3$ for simply connected groups). If this is right then the order 2 outer automorphisms of simple groups of type $D_n$ and $E_6$ should induce $-1$...

Comment: ...but this is a sheer wishful thinking of course...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე This would make an exception of $D_3$ among $D_n$.

Comment: Actually I've computed for $D_{2n+1}$: outer automorphisms induce $+1$ on $H_3$. use the block matrix $J=((0,I),(I,0))$ as quadratic form. Then $J$ itself has determinant $-1$ and is in $O(J)$, so induces the outer automorphism. But a maximal torus in the Lie algebra is given by diagonal matrices $((D,0),(0,-D))$ and $J$ acts as minus identity on it. So it acts as identity on its second symmetric power. Since the Killing form is nonzero on the maximal torus, it means the Killing form is preserved.